Are customs duties and import duties the same?
I've read both terms customs duty and import duty, and it seems they're
being used interchangeably.
The following from DHL (https://www.dhl.com/discover/en-ke/logistics-advice/import-export-advice/what-is-import-duty)
states the following:

Import duty (or customs duty) is a tax collected by customs authorities on all
goods sold across borders [...]

Hillebrand Gori states something similar https://www.hillebrandgori.com/media/publication/duties-tariffs-and-taxes-what-s-the-difference:

An import (also known as a customs duty) is a fee charged on almost every
cross-border shipment of products [...]

However, the following is from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_(tax)
states a broader definition of the term:

A customs duty or due is the indirect tax levied on the import or export of
goods in international trade. In economics a duty is also a kind of
consumption tax. A duty levied on goods being imported is referred to as an
'import duty', and one levied on exports an 'export duty'.

The Wikipedia article rather considers customs duty as something that can be
both, an import duty or an export duty.
As far as I know, customs duties are mostly in the form of import duties
(applied to goods that enter the country).
So, strictly speaking, customs duties are not necessaritly import duties but
can also appear as export duties.
However, since customs duties are (in reality) often applied to imports, they're
commonly referred to as import duties.
Is this assumption correct?

legal terms are defined in laws, colloquially these are used interchangeably but they aren't synonyms.

Most countries do not apply export customs duties (the government likes to promote exports or at least not impede them), and so there import duties and customs duties are equivalent.  A few do (Argentina is a notable example, taxing  many food exports) and in those cases they are not equivalent.

Yes, for practical purposes "customs duties" and "import duties" are the same thing. Technically "customs duties" also includes "export duties", but export duties are extremely rare, and even rarer in the context of shipping personal parcels. Most countries do not impose export duties as it presents a barrier to export trade (the kind of trade most countries are trying to encourage). In the rare case where they do not want a certain commodity to be exported it is controlled in other ways, such as a ban, or requiring permission.

Ultimately what matters is the law in the destination country. It may have different definitions of seemingly identical things so “import duty” in country A is never exactly the same as “import duty” in country B. In fact, many countries' law is not written in English so in this context, “import duty” is also shortcut for the local name. And you can find other phrases in semi-official documents from English-speaking countries, for example gov.uk also uses “duty” (singular, no adjective) and “customs and excise duty” (excise is also something you pay on specific types of imports)…
All that to say that an introduction like the one you found has to be a bit simplistic and you shouldn't read too much in the terminology. Incidentally, while the definition of duty is generally helpful, the following paragraph, on VAT and sales tax, is a confused mess so just take the whole thing with a grain of salt. It's really only meant to tell people who are completely unfamiliar with the topic that there may be something to pay when you move goods across borders. If you need more info, you need to look into the specifics for the relevant countries.
